# SQL search to filter a list of id's

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm curious if there is a crafty way to accomplish the following through SQL only. I have a list of id's from one database and I want to filter this list against another database/table. The requirements are:

1. Search through the table for matching id's; if there is a match and that record meets another constraint (where field2 is null), then remove it from the initial list.
2. Return the results from (1) as well as any id in the initial list which was not found in the second table.

For example, if my list contains id's [1,2,3,4], and my_table that I wish to filter on looks like:

```
+-------+--------+
| my_id | Field2 |
+-------+--------+
|     1 | true   |
|     2 |        |
|     3 | true   |
+-------+--------+
```

Then I expect the final result to be [1,3,4]. Record with id=2 is filtered out because Field2 is null, and 4 remains because its not in the table at all.

So far, all I've come up with is below, which meets requirement (1), but not (2):

```
select distinct my_id
from my_table where my_id IN (1,2,3)  --csv list of id's
and not exists 
(select my_id
   from my_table 
   where my_id IN (1,2,3) and field2 is null)
```

Is there a possibility of using MINUS somehow by creating a temp record set from my initial list of id's?

Comment: what is your database MySQL or MSSQL server ?

Comment: You might want to clarify `1` and `2`. `1` doesn't have any conventional results for `2` to return.

Comment: @Uueerdo updated post with an example. Hope its more clear now.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `WHERE <field> IN <list>` to find all values matching a list:

```
    SELECT DISTINCT t1.my_id
    FROM my_table t1
    LEFT JOIN my_table2 t2 
    ON t1.my_id = t2.field2
    WHERE t1.my_id IN (1,2,3)
      AND t2.field2 IS NULL
```

Comment: Please add an explanation to your answer. How can this code be useful to other users?

Comment: An explanation would be better.